# Загрзука файла на Github Pages через PHP - возможно ли такое?

Tags: php, git, github

Нужно отправить файл на Github Pages через PHP со своего сервера. Есть работающий пример, как это сделать?

Comment: [Возможно](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pages).

Comment: Спасибо, API читал. Мне бы конкретный пример.